# jquery select all text data from the curosr position to first parent div or p

Tags: jquery, html

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
    $(this).select(function(){
        var a = $(this).prevUntil('p').html;
        console.log(a);
    });
</script>


<html>
    <p>dfdsf
        dsfdsf
        <span>sdfdsfds</span><a >sdfdsfdsfdsf</a>sdfsdfdsfdsfds
fsd
f
ds
f
ds
fd</p>
</html>
```

I need to select the whole text from my cursor select position up to the first parent `div` or `p`.

Comment: Afaik, there is not `select` function. If it only was that simple?

Comment: `.prevUntil()` is actually for siblings. I think you're looking for `.closest()`

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "select"?

Comment: selection means just select few words in the document , then we should track all the text content from the selected text upto first div or p

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('p').mouseup(function(){
    if(window.getSelection().toString()!='')
        console.log(window.getSelection().toString());
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/7Xbam/